# Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two 'NSPointerFunctionsOptions' operands

Tags: ios, swift

Getting this error when upgrading to Swift 2 on XCode 7

Error is on the last line in this method.

```
required override init() {
    self.syncStarted=false
    self.syncFrimwareUpdateReboot=false
    self.syncSucceeded=false
    self.syncObservers = NSHashTable(options: NSPointerFunctionsOptions.ObjectPersonality | NSPointerFunctionsOptions.WeakMemory, capacity: 8)
}
```

Comment: did you try use `NSPointerFunctionsOptions.ObjectPersonality.rawValue` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use new Swift 2.0 syntax for options:

```
self.syncObservers = NSHashTable(options: [NSPointerFunctionsOptions.ObjectPersonality, NSPointerFunctionsOptions.WeakMemory], capacity: 8)
```

Comment: Cool, could you give me the link to new syntax? or pages in books?

Comment: @Beraliv tried to find in documentation but failed. I know this from the corrections which Xcode Swift Syntax Converter makes migrating from 1.2 to 2.0. Btw mark as accepted answer if I helped.

Comment: This is not yet in the documentation, the best take is that in general this is how Swift 2 is handling options and it is a good scheme.

Comment: @Beraliv, why would anyone lookup a page number in a book when you can look it up yourself just as well?

Comment: @gnasher729 I didn't ask anyone to find the exact page where it was written down, I got just interested in where it is due to the fact I'm not familiar with that.